# "No Internet connection" on iOS simulator before redirecting after authentication step

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-authentication

I just implemented facebook connect for my web app, and it works fine with my desktop web browser and with android emulator.

But, on iOS 5.0 simulator, after I enter my facebook credentials, instead of redirecting to my app's url, the m.facebook.com page shows an error stating "No Internet Connection. Try again." The left side pane on this page (when disclosed) shows my facebook info, so, the authentication did go through successfully.

Following is the url at which I see the error:

https://m.facebook.com/#!/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_APP_URL&display=wap&response_type=code&fbconnect=1&perms=email&from_login=1&refid=9

BTW, I am redirecting to this url for authentication:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_APP_URL&scope=email.

Any clues on what could be causing the issue ? Appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the url redirection from facebook mobile site to my app is tripping at the MobileSafari's "fraud warning" detection rules.

If I disable "Fraud Warning" in Settings->Safari in the simulator, this works fine.

Need to analyze why safari finds the redirection a problem.